# IOException SEVERE: Error processing request

Tags: java, hibernate

Error
pr 15, 2023 4:46:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor service
SEVERE: Error processing request

java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\TANMAY\Desktop\TT EE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\Micro\upload_93202c4e_25ff_4345_a09c_59717f93cba9_00000007.tmp
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.recycle(Request.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\TANMAY\Desktop\TT EE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\Micro\upload_93202c4e_25ff_4345_a09c_59717f93cba9_00000007.tmp
... 13 more